# How to access MySQL database if access is denied?

Tags: databases, mysql

As part of pentesting I am trying to access/hack a MySQL server using Kali Linux metasploit auxilary with mysql_enum module. But I unable to access it as access is denied.

Does anyone of you have any idea how to access the DB when unauthorized access is denied?

Comment: Have you compromised the database machine itself or are you operating remotely?

Comment: If you don't have valid database credentials, no root access on the server, or a vulnerability in MySQL, a successful attack is unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

Try hydra! It's preinstalled on your Kali box.

`hydra -l root -P <path to passwords file> <ip address of vulnerable box> mysql -V`

This will use all the passwords in the password file supplied to brute force the mysql password for the root account.

A couple good list of password located on every kali box at `/usr/share/wordlists`.  I recommend rock you

Comment: Not to be contrarian but in the interest of lively debate, brute force is always my last resort. If I *know* a box is vulnerable (lab box, vulnhub.com, pen test exam, etc) I will do anything I can before resorting to brute force. It's noisy and slow and if you know there's another vector try those first.

Comment: Yep, agreed.  Maybe you could do an answer using nexpose and a metasploit exploit for whatever old version of mysql metasploitable has.

Comment: I was hoping to hear whether or not he had a shell on the machine already before doing that :)

Comment: Hi @MikeSchem.
. i tried as you suggested, but its not working as expected .. and found the script got stucked .. please have a look at the script 
hydra -l root -P /usr/share/wordlists <target Ip> mysql -V

Hydra v8.2 (c) 2016 by van Hauser/THC - Please do not use in military or secret service organizations, or for illegal purposes.

Hydra (http://www.thc.org/thc-hydra) starting at 2017-03-02 22:33:56
[INFO] Reduced number of tasks to 4 (mysql does not like many parallel connections)

not sure what wrong happend?